# numpy matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I am trying to figure out how to do a kind of scalar matrix multiplication in numpy.

I have

```
a = array(((1,2,3),(4,5,6)))
b = array((11,12))
```

and i want to do

```
a op b
```

to result in

```
array(((1*11,2*11,3*11),(4*12,5*12,6*12))
```

right now I am using the following expression

c= a * array((b, b, b)).transpose()

It seems like there must be a more efficient way of doing this though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking advantage of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
(a.T * b).T
```

Comment: I think that's the transpose of what the question asked for.

Comment: @damien: You're welcome. I'd appreciate it if you mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

The alternative to transposing `a` is to change the shape of `b` to make broadcasting give the result you're looking for:

```
a * b[:, np.newaxis]
```

Note that adding the new axis to b gives the following array:

```
array([[11],
       [12]])
```